# What should happen with how-to questions where doing that thing is a bad idea?

Tags: discussion, questions

Suppose the question was "How do I use a screwdriver as a lever to open a paint can?" We can answer that question ("stick screwdriver tip under edge of lid and press down on the handle") but the better answer in most cases is "Don't do that."

Should the admonition "don't do that" be in the main answer or should it be in a comment attached to the answer or should it be edited into the main question as "Note: This is a bad idea to be avoided." Or something else? I don't think such questions should be closed as "bad questions".

It came up from this question:
[LabVIEW disabled Slider is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764063/labview-disabled-slider-is-enabled?noredirect=1#comment61153795_36764063)
where the question wants to know how to make a particular UI work but that UI creates a particularly negative user experience, but the person asking didn't appear to know the ramifications.

Comment: Using a screwdriver to open a paint can is controversial? A better example would be using a screwdriver to clean out your ears.